# Graphic card doesn't works on Debian even with drivers installed and bumblebee

Tags: linux, debian, nvidia-graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, nouveau

I have an Asus laptop (GL742VW) since three years and I had Windows installed for two. All games worked on my dedicated graphic card without problems.

But now that I use Linux everyday, I would like to play. I tried without doing anything, the games turn on my graphic chipset (Intel HD Graphic 5000). I checked and nouveau doesn't support my GTX960M ([Here it's supported](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/CodeNames/#nv110familymaxwell) but [here it's written TODO](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/VideoAcceleration/#whichcardhaswhatengine)) so I installed the nvidia drivers. Since that none of my games using OpenGL wants to open (they display the "OpenGL GLX extension not supported" error message).

I tried to install bumblebee but then the xserver crashed at startup. I've found out that adding *acpi_osi=! acpi_osi="Windows 2009"* to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line in the grub config solved the crash. But then we returns to the error message above. I tried a lot of things and none of them worked. How can I make it work ?

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers/Optimus

Comment: Thanks the link helped me to find a solution

Comment: If a specific part helped you it would be good for you to write an answer describing which steps fixed it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround on [this link](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers/Optimus#Dynamic_Graphics_Disabled_-_xrandr_and_Display_Manager_Scripts).
The Dynamic Graphics Disabled - xrandr and Display Manager Scripts part worked pretty well (it doesn't use a hybrid config so battery lasts less longer) but I can know launch OpenGL based games !